# C If statement Error: exited with non-zero status

Tags: c

I'm new to c, and I am trying to make a typing game.But the if statement doesn't work,and the output is "exited with non-zero status".May be the problem is cause by the IDE,I can't figure it out,thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (void)
{
  char start;
  printf ("here is a typing game\n");
  printf ("type any key to start\n");
  scanf ("%c", &start);
  void game()
  {
    int i;
    char answer;
    char type[20];
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      {
        printf ("%c", 'a' + (random() % 26));
      }
    }
    scanf ("%s", answer);
    if (strcmp(answer,type) == 0)
    {
      printf ("good\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf ("so bad\n");
    }
  }
  game();
}
```

Comment: scanf ("%s", &answer);

Comment: In C, you can't define a function (in this case, `game`) inside of another function (in this case, `main`). Consult your C manual for further information.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with this code.

1. You can't have a function inside another function (as you have with `game` defined in `main`).
2. `answer` is a single `char`, not a string, so to read it with `scanf` you need to use the line `scanf("%c", &answer);` - if what you wanted was to read a single character, that is; from the rest of your code it seems you intended for `answer` to be a string, so you'd have to declare answer to be a `char [20]` array and call `scanf` with the `"%s"` format specifier.
3. You can't use `strcmp` to compare a `char` to a string. `strcmp` is for comparing strings to strings, not strings to characters or characters to characters. Furthermore, you never assign a string to the array `type` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void game();

int main (void)
{
  char start;

  srand(time(NULL));//seed rand function with time to generate "near to pseudo random numbers"(note: This is not "really" pseudo anyways!)
  printf ("here is a typing game\n");
  printf ("type any key to start\n");
  scanf("%c",&start);
//define your function outside main
  game();//call your function here
}   
void game()
  {
    int i;
    char answer[20];//answer should also be an array
    char type[20]="";//initialize type this way to avoid unnecessary characters initialization

    {
      for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)//should be 19 not 20... Last character has to be null
      {
        printf ("%c", type[i]='a' + (rand() % 26));//You forgot to add the random characters in type array and 
                                                   //rand should be called this way

      }
    }
    scanf ("%s", answer);
    if (strcmp(answer,type) == 0)
    {
      printf ("good\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf ("so bad\n");
    }
  }
```

Suggestion: Improvisations should still be made, like taking input using fgets() and not scanf and managing answer array overflow at input.

Comment: `type` needs to be null-terminated, and also as in the OP's code the function `game` begins within the function `main`.

Comment: the last element in `type` is still uninitialized unless you explicitly declare it to be `\0`.

Comment: @GovindParmar ascii value of NULL is 0. And I have already initialized it with it. char type[20]=""; add a printf("%d",type[0]); just after declaration of type array and you wil get 0 as output.

Comment: @GovindParmar Thanks for voting back :)